# SSRS - Issue with blank table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to build a report that will returns both a customers information and the services they received. So far how I've broken this report is for the customer information I added a "list" and then since I needed the headers on the left side (text boxes with text) and info on the right (text boxes converted to variables). I drug over each variable from my dataset1 individually.

The second box is a 2nd list with a table inside of it representing only the services performed for the customer from dataset2.

[image: ReportSetup]

The problem I am having is if the customer exists it populates the 1st list but if they do not have any services then list 2 disappears and the only thing that exists is the customer information list.

Is there a way to still show the 2nd list with an empty table if no services exist for a current customer??

EDITED:
1st Pic - shows the 2 tables I've added to my report. Diagnosis table is in List1 and the Treatment Plan table is in List2.
[image]

2nd Pic - shows the refreshed report where data exists for the Diagnosis table but the table/list containing the Treatment Plan... is now missing since there is no data available to populate this table.
[image]

Comment: If no rows exist you should see see the table headers. Is this what you mean? If not, edit your question and show your report design and what you are seeing at the moment

Comment: Correct. I'm looking for the table to still be there even if there is no data to populate. So for example in the one picture you can see 2 tables (from the design screen), however in the 2nd picture there is data to populate the 1st box but since there is no data for the 2nd table, it doesn't show on the report. (I added these extra pics to my original post). Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Strange. The table headers **should** show even if there is no data. Make sure the table's `NoRowsMessage` property is completely empty (make sure it's not set to a space for example). Also check the `Hidden` property to make sure that is not being set by an expression. If this still does not help. Post your report design showing any containers such as rectangles etc.